# Issues getting JUnit to not spit errors in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, testing, junit, ide

I've tried uninstalling and re-installing. I've made sure it's in the classpath. I asked my instructor once and they just told me I need to fix it rather than providing me with instructions or clues. I've attached a screenshot to demonstrate. Esentially we're following along to a YT tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aYnMEV9bDqg&list=PLv6UtFrA7VEu4PtzJaGHHSeZBi6mdJtwv&index=1) for eclipse and despite following the instructions to a T, I can't see to get past these errors:

Description: junit cannot be resolved to a module && Description: Test cannot be resolved to a type && Description: TestCase cannot be resolved to a type.

Initially the issue was with JUnit(tutorials 1-5) but in the second section of the tutorial(6-10) we also added test suite which isnt working either.

Again, I've tried uninstalling eclipse and re-installing. I've tried ensuring it's in the class path as well as what I believe to be the relevant .jar file.

Comment: JUnit is an external library, is not included in the JRE / JDK; to use it, you have to import it into your classpath !

Comment: Delete your `module-info.java` file (if needed you can recreate it later via right-click on project and _Configure_) or [in `module-info.java` add the required `requires ...;` statement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform_Module_System#Properties_of_modules).